# Java - Accumulo init exception on OSX Mavericks - log4j logger

Tags: java, macos, exception, logging, accumulo

I am trying to get Accumulo working on OSX Mavericks.  I have Java 1.8, and the most recent Zookeeper and Hadoop installed via Homebrew.  Both of those appears to be working properly.

I downloaded the binaries for Accumulo and I have edited these lines in accumulo/conf/accumulo-env.sh:

```
test -z "$HADOOP_PREFIX"      && export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.0
test -z "$HADOOP_CONF_DIR"     && export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_PREFIX/libexec/etc/hadoop"
test -z "$JAVA_HOME"             && export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
test -z "$ZOOKEEPER_HOME"        && export ZOOKEEPER_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.6
```

However, when I run `bin/accumulo init`, I get:

```
$ bin/accumulo init
Uncaught exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader.<clinit>(AccumuloClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main.main(Main.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I cannot find any useful results searching for this.  I am not sure what could be improperly configured to cause such an error, so I'm not sure where to start.

I have not made any changes to the configurations for Zookeeper or Hadoop, so Hadoop is in its basic standalone mode, which I have confirmed to be working via one of their examples.  Zookeeper starts/stops properly with zkServer.  So I'm guessing the problem is in my Accumulo configuration.  Unfortunately their README is not helpful at all for my situation, and basically just tells me that the Accumulo binaries I've downloaded should just work out of the box.

I have tried running this with the environment variable JAVA_HOME both set and unset, and with it explicitly defined in accumulo-env.sh.

Thank you for anything that can point me in the right direction.  My end-goal is really to be tinkering with GeoMesa, which depends on Accumulo working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configured Accumulo, did you edit `conf/accumulo-site.xml`?

I am assuming you are using Accumulo 1.5.1 and it looks like you are using Hadoop 2.4.0. Inside of `conf/accumulo-site.xml` you need to add some paths to the `general.classpaths` property to pick up all of the JARs used by Hadoop.

Here is what your property for `general.classpaths` should look like:

```
<property>
  <name>general.classpaths</name>
  <!--
     Add the following for Hadoop2, actual needs depend on Hadoop installation details. 
     This list may be excessive, but this should cause no issues. Append these values
     after the $HADOOP_PREFIX entries

     $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/common/.*.jar,
     $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/common/lib/.*.jar,
     $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/hdfs/.*.jar,
     $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/mapreduce/.*.jar,
     $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/yarn/.*.jar,
     /usr/lib/hadoop/.*.jar,
     /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/.*.jar,
     /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.*.jar,
     /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.*.jar,
     /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.*.jar,
  -->
  <value>
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/server/target/classes/,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-server.jar,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/core/target/classes/,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-core.jar,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/start/target/classes/,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-start.jar,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/fate/target/classes/,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-fate.jar,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/proxy/target/classes/,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-proxy.jar,
    $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/[^.].*.jar,
    $ZOOKEEPER_HOME/zookeeper[^.].*.jar,
    $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
    $HADOOP_PREFIX/[^.].*.jar,
    $HADOOP_PREFIX/lib/[^.].*.jar,

    <!-- Added for Hadoop 2 -->
    /usr/lib/hadoop/.*.jar,
    /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/.*.jar,
    /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.*.jar,
    /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.*.jar,
    /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.*.jar,
  </value>
  <description>Classpaths that accumulo checks for updates and class files.
    When using the Security Manager, please remove the ".../target/classes/" values.
  </description>
</property>
```

After configuring this, log4j should be found.

Comment: As it turns out, my problem was probably my own fault.  My setting for HADOOP_PREFIX should have been `HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.0/libexec`, but I had left off the libexec part.  I had accounted for this in the HADOOP_CONF_DIR entry by adding libexec to the path there.  However answer did directly help me solve this, since I found it out by installing Accumulo 1.5.1 (I have been trying to use 1.6) and seeing the commented out configuration hints in the clean config file.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Good to hear that helped!